# How to make a job scheduler run on a single node and not two at the same time?

Tags: cluster-computing, scheduler, quartz

I have a quartz scheduler daemon that is running in a cluster with 2 nodes and I just want it to run on only one node
Where is this configured?
any example please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply configure the other Quartz instance so that it does not start automatically when the daemon application starts. If you use Spring and its `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`, then you simply set its `autoStart` property to false.

See the following example:

```
<bean id="scheduler"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">

  <property name="schedulerName" value="MyQuartzScheduler"/>

  <!--
    Do not auto-start the scheduler instance after it gets constructed.
  -->
  <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>

  <property name="quartzProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
      <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceIdGenerator.class">some_instance_id_generator</prop>
      ...
    </props>
  </property>
  ...
</bean>
```

If you do not use Spring and you construct the Quartz scheduler instance in your code, then simply do not call its start method.

```
SchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();
//scheduler.start();  // DO NOT START
```